# Convert uint64_t to cv::mat

Tags: opencv, type-conversion, uint64, opencv-mat

what I have:

```
 std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
    uint64_t* desc = new uint64_t[8 * keypoints.size()];    
    cv::Mat test = (keypoints.size(), 8, CV_8UC1, desc);
```

That does not work. What am I missing?

Error message is: 
no suitable constructor exists to convert from "uint64_t *" to "cv::Mat" and "Cannot initialize local variable test of type cv::Mat with lvalue of type unsigned long long"
Thank you

Comment: Tell us what error you're seeing? Also, the first two arguments are the width and height of the image, unless you have an 8x8 pixel image, that's probably wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question to reflect the actual code and added error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for calling the `cv::Mat` constructor is incorrect, try:

```
cv::Mat test(keypoints.size(), 8, CV_8UC1, desc);
```

Comment: Haha, you are right. I was looking for something complicated when it was really simple. Thank you.